# What are 'modules' in intellij IDEA,actually? Is it different from a Java module?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I switched to IntelliJ IDEA a few days back and I did some research around the IDE. Like what the .iml, .idea, etc files/ directories were.
But I dont get what the 'src' folder is. Other answers here have indicated that its a module, but i'm on JDK 1.8 which does'nt have the modularity features of JDK 9. So what is that folder anways?

Comment: There's a difference between an _IntelliJ IDEA Module_ and a _Java Module_.

Comment: Check out [Modules - Help | IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html). The `src` directory is a [content root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html). Both of those are related to IntelliJ specifically. The module system added in Java 9 is part of Java itself; an IntelliJ module may contain a Java 9 module.

Comment: @Slaw Appreciate the link, it clarified the confusion. Thank you

Comment: I suggest you rework the title of this Question to focus on the word “module” rather than “src”. This might avoid down-votes, and would help future people new to Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are conflating two or three different kinds of “module”.

## Maven modules

In a Maven-driven project, quite common among Java developers, a project can be built up from multiple sub-projects each separately compiled. These sub-projects are called [modules in Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

## IntelliJ project modules

Years before the rise of open source code manage,ent tools & dependencies project management tools like [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle), and [Ivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ivy), IDEs each had their own proprietary project management systems and file formats for metadata.

If I recall correctly, IntelliJ’s proprietary system for defining a project included “modules”.

If you are using a proprietary project tool for your project, I strongly suggest starting over with a new Maven-driven project, or Gradle-driven project. Both Maven and Gradle bring a bit of a learning curve. The learning is well worth the effort as either tool saves much time and trouble later. Also, a Maven or Gradle project can be easily moved to another IDE if you ever want to switch tools.

## Java modularity

Java 9 introduced a major addition to how classes are organized, in addition to the [*package* namespace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html). This is known formally as [*Java Platform Module System*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System). Also known informally by its project code name, [*Project Jigsaw*](https://openjdk.org/projects/jigsaw/).

The Module System defines a distribution format for physically bundling classes and a [JVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) together. The standard classes that were formerly all bundled together with every JVM have now been regrouped into separate Java modules. You can now build a console app or desktop app that contains its own JVM with only the standard classes actually used by your app. Entire modules of standard Java classes can be omitted, reducing the size of your final app.

This Module System is a separate idea from the other two project “module” kinds discussed above.